# Remove whitespaces after number - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, extract

Basically, I want to remove the whitespace that exists after numbers

Input:

```
medication_title

CLORIDRATO DE VENLAFAXINA 75 MG
VIIBRYD 40 MG
KTRIZ UNO 0.6 U/G
```

Ouput:

```
medication_title                     medication_title2

CLORIDRATO DE VENLAFAXINA 75 MG     CLORIDRATO DE VENLAFAXINA 75MG 
VIIBRYD 40 MG                       VIIBRYD 40MG
KTRIZ UNO 0.6 U/G                   KTRIZ UNO 0.6U/G
```

Ideas?

Comment: Capture them and replace them by an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT
    medication_title,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(medication_title,
                   '\y(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ([^[:space:]]*G)\y',
                   '\1\2') AS medication_title2
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `\y` word boundary
- `(` match and capture in `\1`

  - `\d+` a number
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` followed by optional decimal component
- `)` close capture group `\1`
- match a space (the one we want to remove)
- `(` match and capture in `\2`

  - `[^[:space:]]*` zero or more leading non whitespace characters
  - `G` folllwed by "G"
- `)` close capture group `\2`
- `\y` another word boundary

Comment: I have the impression this answer works better than mine under special cases.

Comment: Your answer is fine, but I tried to be more precise, to avoid the sort of edge cases which you might have in mind.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, would you mind further explain `(?:\.\d+)?)`

Comment: I have added a detailed explanation of the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the sequences with a regular expression and then assemble them back as needed, as in `regexp_replace(x, '([^0-9]*[0-9]) +([^0-9\.]+)', '\1\2')`.

For example:

```
select *, regexp_replace(x, '([^0-9]*[0-9]) +([^0-9\.]+)', '\1\2') as y
from (
  select 'CLORIDRATO DE VENLAFAXINA 75 MG'
  union all select 'VIIBRYD 40 MG'
  union all select 'KTRIZ UNO 0.6 U/G  '
) t (x)
```

Result:

```
x                                y                              
-------------------------------- ------------------------------ 
CLORIDRATO DE VENLAFAXINA 75 MG  CLORIDRATO DE VENLAFAXINA 75MG 
VIIBRYD 40 MG                    VIIBRYD 40MG                   
KTRIZ UNO 0.6 U/G                KTRIZ UNO 0.6U/G
```